# Should I add mobile sitemap to my initial full sitemap?

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, xml-sitemap

Do I need to add mobile sitemaps for a mobile enabled site or will just the standard sitempas do. The platform generator has created quite a few different sitemaps. Will it be too much to submit all of these?

not really quite sure what a mobile sitemap would bring you.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3ArIuPt8mKRSl9tWWFWWFRqc1FUWVN6WlA3ek9CSEUxYV9R

Answer (score 1):

If the only difference between the desktop version and mobile version of your site are only graphics related (such as any color or image changes), then making a sitemap for each site is pointless since the content (which google defines as webpage text) is the same on both versions of each page.

In this case, make a sitemap for the desktop version of the site and on each mobile page, add rel=canonical pointing to the desktop version of the same page.

See this for more info: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Also, remove all other URLs in your sitemap that point to pages of content that is duplicate of any other content found on the internet. Google does not like to index duplicate content.